# Why does LINQ not work to add DataRows to a DataTable?

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, expandoobject

To shoehorn ExpandoObjects into something grids like the following two attempts were made.

This doesn't work:

```
var data = _d.Query<dynamic>(_script);         // returns IEnumerable<ExpandoObject>

IDictionary<string, object> c = (IDictionary<string, object>)data.FirstOrDefault();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt.BeginLoadData();
dt.Columns.AddRange(c.Keys.Select(k => new DataColumn(k)).ToArray());
data.Select(r => dt.Rows.Add((r as IDictionary<string, object>).Values.ToArray()));
dt.EndLoadData();
```

But this does:

```
dt.Columns.AddRange(c.Keys.Select(k => new DataColumn(k)).ToArray());
foreach (IDictionary<string, object> r in data)
  dt.Rows.Add(r.Values.ToArray());
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Select Method**

> The query represented by this method is not executed until the object
>   is enumerated either by calling its GetEnumerator method directly or
>   by using foreach in Visual C# or For Each in Visual Basic.

So this select is never executed:

```
data.Select(r => dt.Rows.Add((r as IDictionary<string, object>).Values.ToArray()));
```

Reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb548891.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but try soemthing like this instead:

```
data.Cast<Dictionary<string, object>>().ToList().ForEach(x => dt.Rows.Add(x.Values.ToArray()));
```

Comment: ForEach is not part of linq. It's a List member.

Comment: I know... did I say it was linq?

Answer (score 0):

As sailor already pointed out, LINQ is lazily evaluated. Placing a `.LastOrDefault()` on the end of your query will cause execution (because by trying to get the last element it will execute your `Select()`), *however* it will make your code look even worse!

By definition, LINQ Select should not be used for side-effecting behaviour. I believe you should be able to see that in your question option 2 looks much cleaner than option 1. By reading option 2, I can easily understand, that you are adding each element of `data` to the datatable. By reading option 1, I'd guess you're doing something to the `data` variable, which would be wrong.

In conclusion, just stick with option 2. When performance is the same (as this is the case), try to make your code as "easy" to read as possible. A random person should be able to get the general idea without reading through the whole thing.